# Update com SET dando erro

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Tenho vários `UPDATE` com praticamente o mesmo código que este:

```
UPDATE cliente
  SET Email = 'nome.sobrenome@empresa.com.br'
  WHERE idCliente = 0000;
```

Mas alguns dão este erro:

> Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Email' at row 1

Comment: Qual o tipo e o tamanho do campo email?

Comment: No scheme de sua tabela confira o tipo e a quantidade de caracteres que setou para a coluna 'Email' se retorna data too long é porque excedeu o limite configurado

Comment: você vai precisar de um `ALTER TABLE cliente CHANGE Email Email VARCHAR(255)` no lugar de 255 altere para o tamanho que desejar mas pode ser 255 mesmo. Você deve especificar o nome da coluna `Email` 2 vezes se quiser alterar apenas a definição da coluna (e não o nome da mesma). Para também alterar o nome da mesma, forneça o novo nome após o nome da mesma `ALTER TABLE cliente CHANGE Email NovoNome VARCHAR(255)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mensagem de erro é clara sobre o que está acontecendo: os dados são longos demais para a coluna `Email`.

Está tentando gravar 29 caracteres, certamente esta coluna está configurada na tabela com um tamanho menor do que este, ou coloque um dado menor ou coloque um tamanho maior na coluna.

Note ainda que se os caracteres saírem do espectro do que se chama tabela ASCII o caractere ocupará 2 ou mais bytes o que pode fazer, dependendo da configuração da tabela, precisa de uma reserva maior ainda.